# Are there risks to having variables that have the same name as inputs to a function?

Tags: python

Example Code Below:

```
path = "C:/users/name/Desktop/"

def rename_files(dir, new, path):
    os.rename(path+dir, path+new)
```

My question is, are there risks to having the path variable defined and then also having an input to function rename_files as "path"?

Comment: Your global `path` and your function argument `path` are entirely separate variables. There is no risk of Python confusing the two. There is only the risk of you or another programmer confusing them.

Comment: No, (unless you also want to use the global variable *path* in your function :)) ). What I'd suggest is to rename *dir*, as it's shadowing the builtin function with the same name.

Comment: @khelwood Got it, that makes sense. It doesn't seem like I can mark yours as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global variable `path` and your function argument `path` are entirely separate variables. There is no risk of Python confusing the two. There is only the risk of you or another programmer confusing them.